# Is FeatureUpgrading supposed to use the latest Property values?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

The 1.0.0.0 version of my Feature's Template.xml file looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Properties>
    <Property Key="AvailableWebTemplates" Value="MPS#0;MPS#1;MPS#2;MPS#3;MPS#4" />
  </Properties>
</Feature>
```

The new version 1.1.0.0 is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <UpgradeActions>
  <VersionRange BeginVersion="1.0.0.0" EndVersion="1.1.0.0">
   <CustomUpgradeAction Name="UpgradeTo1v1"/>
  </VersionRange>
 </UpgradeActions>
  <Properties>
    <Property Key="AvailableWebTemplates" Value="MPS#0;MPS#1;MPS#2;MPS#3;MPS#4;STS#2" />
  </Properties>
</Feature>
```

The value of `templates` is still `MPS#0;MPS#1;MPS#2;MPS#3;MPS#4`, when the following code runs in FeatureUpgrading:

```
SPFeatureProperty property = properties.Feature.Properties["AvailableWebTemplates"];
string templates = property.Value;
```

Why am I not getting the updated property value? Is this the way it is supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed the way it is supposed to be:
A feature has 1 definition and n instances. The code in FeatureUpgrading is used to upgrade the *instances*.

The property in your xml updates the feature definition and not the running instances.

`properties.Feature.Properties["MyProp"]` gets the property value of the *running instance*   `properties.Definition.Properties["MyProp"]` gets the value of the property in the *feature definition*.

Comment: Interesting. So I guess since this is FeatureUpgrading instead of FeatureUpgraded, this gives me the opportunity to compare the instance to the definition to see what is different.

How I initially got this to work was to add a Parameters section to my CustomUpgradeAction. I haven't decided if I like that or not. I suppose if there are multiple versions, having the values in the Parameters will give me a history of how the Feature has been upgraded. But then I already have source control that tells me that, so I think I'll take it out and go with properties.Definition. Thanks!